# Подскажите ошибку в Java

Tags: java, catch

Подскажите что нужно делать чтобы в one_turn catch вернул ошибку если х не равно 1 или 2.

```
public class Main {

    // Random number function in range of 10 - 20
    public static int random_number_gen(){
        int number = 10 + (int)(Math.random() * ((20 - 10) + 1));
        return number;
    }

    static int users_turn = 1;

    public static int get_from_player(){
        System.out.println("Player" + users_turn + " enter either 1 or 2 ");
        Scanner asking_for_guess = new Scanner(System.in);
        int data = Integer.parseInt(asking_for_guess.nextLine());


        return data;
    }

    public static int one_turn(){

        try{
            int x = get_from_player();
            if (x == 1 || x == 2) {
                return x;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception err){
            System.out.println("Please provide an integer, either 1 or 2 !");
            return one_turn();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете выбрасывать исключения самостоятельно.

```
public static int one_turn() {

    int x = get_from_player();
    if (x == 1 || x == 2) {
        return x;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("incorrect digit!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное